# reading a specific line from a large file

Tags: c++, fstream, cin

I have to build a "text corrector" in C++. Meaning the teacher will use a random English ".txt" file and use our program to detect and correct errors. To do so, we are provided with an English dictionary of something like... 350k different words. Each word occupies one line. We have to check for each word in his .txt file if the word exists in dictionary.txt.

Now... the main problem of this is how to use the dictionary. Since the words vary in length, I can't use a table to load them all then do binary search in the table when i need to find a word.

I am hoping there is a way to simply move around in the file. Most answers around here say "loop" around the file, but that is not a possibility here, because we are evaluated on the execution speed and the file has 350k words. Looping around 350k words for a few thousand time to correct a file would be way to long.

Knowing the length of the file, couldn't I just say "go to middle of file, compare the word, move around to a quarter (or three) of the file, etc"? because i have the file and i know the precise size... Like a "go to line this" or "go to this character"- and from there i can simply move a few char back or forward to get the full word...

Comment: *Since the words vary in length, i can hardly use a table* -- Think again.  I would believe there is no need for file work here, except at the beginning where you're reading in the words from the dictionary.  350k words is nothing in this day and age.  Just store the words in an `std::unordered_map` and do a `find` on it to see if a word exists.

Comment: It will be faster to load the whole file into memory. And I don't understand why you want to move parts of the file around.

Comment: For this kind of thing, the standard template library is the way to go.  In this particular case, load the the dictionary into a std::set ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/ ) and then look up the words from the text in the set.

Comment: Some advise if you are going to make programming into a career: Do not attempt to learn from high school or college teachers. If they manage to teach you anything at all, they will teach you incorrectly. You absolutely must learn programming through self study, books, and online resources. Go to school only to get the paper that proves you know what you claim to know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem calls for a radix tree.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

It allows you to create, store, and search the dictionary of words much more efficiently then a map when it comes to this kind of problem.

As you compare, when you see letters 'c','o','r' you can explore each branch and see that it could possibly match with "core", "correctly", or "corporation", for example.

If you check online algorithm practice sites like HackerRank, or have been interviewed by Amazon or Microsoft, this problem is going to come up.